# Navbar to change colour on scroll bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi guys so i want my navbar to be able to switch colors from transparent to black as soon as the user scrolls, now this code worked on my bootstrap 3 website but when i have changed to bootstrap 4 it didn't work for some reason

html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav" role="navigation">
...
  </nav>
```

CSS: This just making it transparent

```
.bg-dark {
      background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0)!important;
      padding-top: 20px;
}
```

javascript :

```
       $(document).ready(function(){

     var checkScrollBar = function(){
       $('.bg-dark').css({
         backgroundColor: $(this).scrollTop() > 1 ?
           'rgb(0, 0, 0)' : 'transparent'
       })
     }
     $(window).on('load resize scroll', checkScrollBar)
     });
```

Again this was working on my other site but on this one i cant seem to get it to work for some reason ,

thanks

Comment: i think i need to add !important to javascript but i aient sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work by removing `!important` rule in your CSS. With that rule there, jQuery **will** change the background colour inline, but the browser will choose the `!important` style over the change, so it will not be visually reflected.

This whole line might be unnecessary because you are using jQuery to set the background color to transparent anyway:

```
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0)!important;
```

Comment: Ye i just had to go into the bootstrap file and take out !important, what a silly thing they did, no idea why they did that

Answer (score 2):

With Javascript only :

```
<!-- Custom JS for background color on scrolling -->
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll < 300){
        $('.fixed-top').css('background', 'transparent');
    } else{
        $('.fixed-top').css('background', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)');
    }
});
</script>
```